# BigQuery: suppressing "Error 404: Not found: Table..."

Tags: google-bigquery

I have BigQuery tables like below.

```
AAAAAA_yyyymmdd
BBBBBB_yyyymmdd
CCCCCC_yyyymmdd
```

I would like to retrieve data which are inserted in this one minute. I executed the SQL like below.

```
SELECT * FROM [AAAAAA_20170515@-60000-],[BBBBBB_20170515@-60000-],[CCCCCC_20170515@-60000-]
```

This SQL works fine if all `AAAAAA_20170515` and `BBBBBB_20170515` and `CCCCCC_20170515` exists, but not all tables are created every day. 
If some tables are missing, I got the error like below.

```
Error 404: Not found: Table BBBBBB_20150515, notFound
```

I would like to ignore tables that do not exist. I know I can do that first checking if each table exists, then construct SQL. But it is desirable if I can suppress `Error 404: Not found: Table` error for efficiency.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using [Wildcard Tables with _TABLE_SUFFIX filter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables#best_practices), although it will perform better if you have a common prefix to the tables.

For example:

```
SELECT * from `vimota.PREFIX*` where _TABLE_SUFFIX = '_20170515';
```

Comment: I would like to use [table decorator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators). Wildcard Table does not support it.

Comment: You're right, there's no way to do what you're asking exactly, currently. I would suggest doing it programmatically like you alluded to by running `SELECT table_id FROM vimota.__TABLES__ WHERE table_id like '%_20170515'`, getting all the existing tables and building a query with them in the FROM clause.